# Error "Unable to step. The method or operation is not implemented." in Revolution R when step-by-step debugging

Tags: r, revolution-r

As in the question, in certain rare situations, when attempting to perform step-by-step debugging in Revolution R, an error message is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Revolution R v7.0 works perfectly when step-by-step debugging.

However, executing this line will prevent step-by-step debugging from working:

```
options(error=recover)
```

The solution is to set error recovery back its defaults, then step-by-step debugging will start to work perfectly again:

```
options(error=NULL)
```

To reproduce this error, create a ReferenceClass in R with an `initialize` method, set `options(error=recover)`, then attempt to debug into the `initialize` method.

You will get the error "Unable to step. The method or operation is not implemented." if you have a breakpoint inside the `initialize` method:

[image]

You will get this error if you attempt to step over the `initialize` method:

[image]